# Changing the order of the integration $\int_{-1}^1\int_0^\sqrt{1-x^2}\int_{x^2+y^2}^1fdzdydx$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I would like to express the integral
$$\int_{-1}^1\int_0^\sqrt{1-x^2}\int_{x^2+y^2}^1fdzdydx$$
in the order $dxdydz$. I find $$\int_0^1\int_\sqrt{z}^1\int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^\sqrt{1-y^2}fdxdydz.$$ Could anyone check my result? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $x^2+y^2\leq z\leq 1$ and $y\geq 0$, then the triple integral should be
$$\int_{z=0}^1\int_{y=0}^\sqrt{z}\int_{x=-\sqrt{z-y^2}}^\sqrt{z-y^2}fdxdydz$$

Comment: I realized that I did draw the wrong region! This makes sense. Thanks!